# Forumla to Determine Redness from RBG Value

Tags: image, colors, rgb

I'm looking for a formula to determine the redness of an RGB color.  I'm sure there's some very simple formula, but I haven't been able to find it.

Basically, it would be something like this:

```
function rednessAsPercent(r, g, b) {
  // Does some math to determine redness.
}

alert(rednessAsPercent(255, 0, 0)); // Alerts: 100
alert(rednessAsPercent(255, 255, 0)); // Alerts: 0.  This is pure yellow.
alert(rednessAsPercent(255, 122, 122)); // Alerts: ~50.  This is sort of pink.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A term like redness is relative, it is in the eye of the beholder. You need to quantify what it signifies before you can program a solution.

Comment: @MarkHall - Makes sense.  I'm trying to digest this HSL/HSV color space stuff.  I think what I really want to do is have a path (a gradient) between two colors/points and then attempt to see if a color is on that path.  If so, how far along.  If not, how far from and how far some projection onto that path is.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to come up with a better definition of what "redness" means - on what scale (presumably red-blue-yellow)

This might be useful:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space

Comment: Thanks. See comment above for more detail on my condition.

Comment: So it's a 3D vector problem - there'll be a simple mathematical solution once you select a colour space.